# Access denied while uploading picture to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have created an aws account from aws educate. I am trying to upload a picture to aws s3. But I get an access denied error.

Code:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const config = require('../config');

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Invalid file type, only JPEG and PNG is allowed!'), false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    acl: 'private',
    s3,
    bucket: 'acc-partner',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {
        fieldName: 'TESTING_METADATA'
      });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const UserCtrl = require('../controllers/user');

const upload = require('../services/image-upload');

const singleUpload = upload.single('image');


router.post('/image-upload', UserCtrl.authMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message}]});
    }

    return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

error in postman

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "title": "Image Upload Error",
            "detail": "Access Denied"
        }
    ]
}
```

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZEr3.jpg)
[picture of setting in aws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QNri.jpg)

Comment: Hello, avoid image links and print the error you get in the post

Comment: I didnot get any specific error in console 
just I get error in postman

Comment: Could you please provide the bucket policy and CORS settings. Most likely you haven't allowed IAM user to write to the bucket.

Comment: @Milan
`{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::acc-partner/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: i have not set any thing in CORS

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to set the policy to allow your IAM user (the one with AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID from your example) to upload data.

The policy should look like this:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
         ],
         "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::123exampleaccountID:user/Jane"
          ]
         },
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::acc-partner/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

What this does is allows your IAM user (you should replace `arn:aws:iam::123exampleaccountID:user/Jane` with your IAM user ARN) to upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't set the public policy for the bucket (as I can saw in the AWS image). Try to set your bucket policy to public (click on the button Bucket Policy).

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::acc-partner/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can play around with the policy generator here https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html.

Answer (score 0):

The IAM user you have generated access keys for does not have PUT access to the s3 bucket you are attempting to put the image in.

For the user associated with the access keys specified in your config file, go to the IAM dashboard, and create a new policy with the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To further restrict requests to only those PUT requests that come from your ec2 server, go to the ec2 dashboard, reserve a static ip address, and use the following policy instead:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "YOUR_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS/16"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Once done, attach the new policy to the user in the IAM console.